# Web Java variables reset

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I made website with Hibernate and Struts 2 with using of Ajax in Java. Basically, when I create, modify any local content (in .java), like assign value to `int`, at next inspection its `null`. This happens every time.

This is the `struts.xml` most of my pages are bidden this way:

```
<action name="showclient" class="modelClass.LogInObject" method="show">
    <result name="success" >/MyAccount.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Client is just a bin class with CRUD implemented:

```
public class Client extends ActionSupport   {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long idClient;
private String login;
private String password;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String adresse;
private String ville;
private int cPostal;
private String email;
private Set<Commande> panier = new HashSet<Commande>(0);
//  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

public static Client logIn(String login, String password)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String qstr = "SELECT * FROM client";
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(qstr).addEntity(Client.class);
    List<Client> list = (List<Client>)query.list();
    Iterator<Client> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Client client = it.next();
        if (client.getLogin().compareTo(login) == 0 &&
            client.getPassword().compareTo(password) == 0)
            return client;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `LogInObject`:

```
public class LogInObject extends ActionSupport   {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long    loggedInId;
private String  login;
private String  password;
private String  confirmPassword;
private String  error;
public Client   client;

public  String login()
{
    Client client = null;
    if ((client = Client.read(Client.logIn(this.login, this.password).getIdClient())) != null)
    {
        this.client = client;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    this.login = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.error = "Bad login or password";
    return ERROR;
}

public  String  show()
{
    System.out.println(this.getClient().getIdClient());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And finally main class:

```
public class MainActionObject extends ActionSupport   {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean logged;
private String  search;

List<Produit>   listProduit;

LogInObject     loginObject;

public String login()
{
    if (this.loginObject.login() == SUCCESS)
    {
        this.setLogged(true);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return ERROR;
}
}
```

So the `show()` in `loginobject` prints id of client that was read from SQL base at the moment of initialization I print it to the `.jsp` page all info r there and after all it no longer exist. even if I make a backup of id in any possible way. I know the meaning of CRUD, so don't tell me its normal.

Comment: What inspection do you mean?

Comment: for example when i initialize and id of client, when he logs in. he click edit button, and i want to read the client from sql by id. the id i had before is null now.

Comment: Where do you store that id?

Comment: one of my classes, that is not mapped in hibernate, java class

Comment: How do you access that class with request. Put some code out.

Comment: Ok,
so i use struts to link the pages.

<action name="showclient" class="modelClass.LogInObject" method="show">
         <result name="success" >/MyAccount.jsp</result>
</action>

have the same for most of my pages, links. When user loggs in i stock his id in modelClass 

public class MainActionObject extends ActionSupport   {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static Long id;
 private boolean logged;
 private String search;
 
 List<Produit> listProduit;
 
 LogInObject  loginObject;
{...}
}

whenever i recheck the value of id it is null, but the moment afte i set

Comment: @BadabumMan edit your question, avoid posting code in comments if it is too large

Comment: Actions are instantiated per-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your action needs to `extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware`

and when your client logged in successfully

```
public  String login()
{
  ...
  getServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("idClient", client.getIdClient()); 

public  String  show()
{
  System.out.println(getServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("idClient"));
```

Comment: It works, i can stock things in session.
Anyway, put() is depricated use setAttribute and get Attribute instead

Comment: That guys always change their apis don't know how it will be name next decade.

Comment: This is a terrible way to get the session; implement SessionAware instead. Ugh.