# How to have access to ServletRequestAware on struts2-core 2.3.16.1?

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

I changed my struts2 version from 2.3.14 to 2.3.16.1, it seems that newest version does not support `ServletRequestAware` and `ServletResponseAware` anymore, what should I do? I could not find anything online.

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>    
</dependency>
```

**Code**

```
 import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
 public class MyExample implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {
```

**Error**

```
package org.apache.struts2.interceptor does not exist.
```

When I try to find a dependency for it Maven shows the latest version of Struts2 which is supporting it is 2.3.14!

Comment: Just go with 2.3.16, **IF** 2.3.16.1 is not well supported

Comment: I need to use struts-jquery-plugin and thats the reason that I should use 2.3.16 above versions, but none of them support ServletRequestAware.

Comment: my question is if I use the newer versions how can I access ServletRequests

Comment: Why do you say they don't support ServletRequestAware ? They do, afaik

Comment: As mentioned in the question, when I use them, a pre-compiled error will be shown on the imports

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; that class is packaged in all the 2.3 releases.

Answer (score 0):

At the [How To Create A Struts 2 Web Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application) add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

Check the file version X.X.X.X is available in the repository and downloaded to your hard drive.

Comment: both 2.3.16 and 2.3.16.1 are also available to download

Comment: If I use 2.3.16 or 2.3.16.1 , how can I have access to ServletRequests?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802952/573032 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292411/573032 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13545669/573032

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some problem with the libraries included in your project;

- Be sure to erase all the old JARs from the classpath (your WAR / EAR and shared libs on the AS;
- run Clean Project in your IDE;
- download Struts2.3.16.1 from Maven or manually [from here](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi);
- check out the `ServletRequestAware` and `ServletResponseAware` Interfaces at

  ```
  /struts-2.3.16.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/
  ```

  , exactly where they were before ;)

E.g., output from 2.3.16.3 distribution:

```
$ jar tvf struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar | grep ServletRequest
223 Fri May 02 17:23:44 EDT 2014 org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.class
```

It's also in the 2.3.16.1 jars.